# How to add glpk to shinyapp.io

Tags: python, r, shinyapps, glpk

I'm using R and python, from R i've invoke python, so all is well till i try to opt = pyo.SolverFactory('glpk'), this is on python, gives me this next error: "Could not locate the 'glpsol' executable, which is required for solver 'glpk'". So i need to add glpk to a shinyapp.io instance becasuse i don't have a clue on how to do it.

this is how i invoke my code on R

```
    virtualenv_create("r-reticulate")
    py_install("pyomo")
    py_install("pandas")
    source_python("model_function.py") 
    model = create_model(X,Y)
```

i try to add this librareis

```
library("plyr")
library("ROI")
library("ROI.plugin.glpk")
library("Rglpk")
library("glpkAPI")
library("geosphere")
library("dplyr")
library("plotly") # Sirve para hacer dinámicos los gráficos y descargar imágenes entre otras cosas 
library("slam")
library("shinyjs") # Sirve para usar JavaScript en la aplicación shiny
library("openxlsx") # Sirve para leer CSVs
library("rsconnect") #para subir la aplicación
library("reticulate")
```

Comment: From https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/227057448-Are-there-any-limitations-to-the-packages-I-can-use-in-an-app-I-deploy-to-shinyapps-io-: *"R packages will often rely on operating system packages to be installed on the server. If your application happens to use an R package that requires a system library that is not installed by default, please let us know by filing an issue, or a pull request, at: [shinyapps-package-dependencies](https://github.com/rstudio/shinyapps-package-dependencies)"*. I assume it applies to python packages as well, you'll need to ask them.